# How to evaluate a Classifier model against the Ground Truth with missing labels?

Tags: machine-learning, precision-recall, model-evaluation, precision, labeling

I want to evaluate my classifier model (Facebook `FastText`) against the ground truth. My dataset has two labels let's say `A` and `B`, so I have a binary classifier model. After the training (train and test split 80/20 or 70/30) I get my **P**,**R** i.e. the `Precision`, `Recall`values at `k` (*P@k* and *R@k*).

My `Ground Truth` (of a given size) has a lack of a label i.e. I have only the label `A`, but any samples of the label `B` i.e. in the ground truth I have correct labeling (by human expert)for `A`, and any labeling for `B`.
Hence I can estimate against the ground truth the error rate for the label `A`, but not for the label `B`, because of missing samples.

Assumed that I have for the `TestSet` the correct evaluation of **P** and **R**, is there a way to estimate (worst/best case) the error rate for the `B` label as well?